# How could I change the audio output device of node module "say"

Tags: node.js, powershell, electron, text-to-speech, playback

I'm making a program that will output text to speech, the user will need to be able to change the output device (for example to [virtual audio cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable)). At the moment I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/say to produce the speech
e.g.

```js
const say = require("say");
say.speak("Hello World");
```

but I've no clue on how I could go about choosing the audio output.

What I've found so far has been pretty useless, I'm guessing largely because I don't know the proper terminology to search for answers, regardless this is it:

I first found out about [navigator.MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices), then I found how I could make an audio element and change the audio device of that element via [setSinkId](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId), then I realized these things are probably(?) irrelevant since the say module seems to play sounds using powershell commands. I've even gone as far as trying to change powershell's output device in app [volume device preferences(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1v2p.png), but that seems to do nothing.

I'm pretty much stumped right now, so I'd appreciate any help please. I'm not set on using Say as a module, it just seemed easy to use at first.

---

Edit:

A workaround I've settled with is making my own TTS class and using [SpVoice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723602(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
I have something similar to this:

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');
class TTS {
    constructor(channel, speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.baseCommand = "$speak = New-Object -ComObject SAPI.SPVoice;"
    }
    speak(text){
        var command = this.baseCommand +
            `$speak.AudioOutput = foreach ($o in $speak.GetAudioOutputs()) {if ($o.getDescription() -eq '${this.channel}') {$o; break;}}; `
            + "$speak.Speak([Console]::In.ReadToEnd());"

        this.child = childProcess.spawn('powershell', [command], {shell: true})
        this.child.stdin.setEncoding('ascii')
        this.child.stdin.end(text);
        this.child.addListener('exit', (code, signal) => {
            if (code === null || signal !== null) {
              console.log(new Error(`error [code: ${code}] [signal: ${signal}]`))
            }
            this.child = null
        })
    }
}
```

Then I can pass in an audio channel like

```js
tts = new TTS("CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)", 0);
tts.speak("Hello there");
```

and it will output TTS in my desired channel

Answer (score 0):

Some of the browsers support the built in speechSynthesis API.

Save the following code in 'test.html' file and open the file in chrome web browser for testing the speech api.

```
<script>

    //---------------- SpeechAPI Start ------------------------
    
    function speak(message) {
      try {
        
        var utterance= new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("");
        utterance.lang='en-GB'; 
        utterance.text=message;
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);

      }catch(e){
        console.log('Exception in speak : ' + e)
      }
    }
    
    //---------------- SpeechAPI End ------------------------

</script>

<button onclick="speak('Hello, how are you doing?');">Press to speak</button>
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no my issue isn't how to produce text to speech, it's in choosing the output channel for it.